# regular expression for challenge value

Tags: regex, recaptcha

**what will be the regular expression to extract challenge var value**

i am interested in this vlaue

**03AHJ_Vut9LJLOJuCsjF9PbSSMncTyUe7Y4dHX11eRLae3LGfDZ0hSfDR7jZq2ZrKJxyC-LRSSppv72oHKaQMsd-EnoVNL6p7liTh7siN26zzTA_E2rcC_JQ15613Azz4qm8HjPtAyksUdc7QZydszwolk92hBPrAAig**

this value changes every time we refresh it so the expression has to be generic enough to pick up what ever is the value

```
var RecaptchaState = {
site : '6LeKCL8SAAAAADV5Dr-lfY2eOEV8rubeN25BAKp2',
challenge : '03AHJ_Vut9LJLOJuCsjF9PbSSMncTyUe7Y4dHX11eRLae3LGfDZ0hSfDR7jZq2ZrKJxyC-LRSSppv72oHKaQMsd-EnoVNL6p7liTh7siN26zzTA_E2rcC_JQ15613Azz4qm8HjPtAyksUdc7QZydszwolk92hBPrAAig',
is_incorrect : false,
programming_error : '',
error_message : '',
server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
timeout : 18000};
```

any help will be appreciated, or any method to extract this value in any server side lang

Comment: What are you extracting the "challenge" from and what are the properties of this value? Is the length fixed? Can it have whitespace? Is it somehow delimited? And what is that code segment at the bottom? Is that the structure that you are going to put the "challenge" in?

Comment: length is fixed, it cant have a white space, its a js file for recaptha generated from my public key, i need value for challenge var, this is the image path to display for people to fill in on my online script

Comment: Are you actually trying to extract the value from the js source text?

Comment: yes here is the js file http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeKCL8SAAAAADV5Dr-lfY2eOEV8rubeN25BAKp2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Perl script that do the job:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

while(<DATA>) {
    say $1 if (/^\s*challenge : '(.+?)'/)
}

__DATA__
var RecaptchaState = {
site : '6LeKCL8SAAAAADV5Dr-lfY2eOEV8rubeN25BAKp2',
challenge : '03AHJ_Vut9LJLOJuCsjF9PbSSMncTyUe7Y4dHX11eRLae3LGfDZ0hSfDR7jZq2ZrKJxyC-LRSSppv72oHKaQMsd-EnoVNL6p7liTh7siN26zzTA_E2rcC_JQ15613Azz4qm8HjPtAyksUdc7QZydszwolk92hBPrAAig',
is_incorrect : false,
programming_error : '',
error_message : '',
server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
timeout : 18000};
```

**Output :**

```
03AHJ_Vut9LJLOJuCsjF9PbSSMncTyUe7Y4dHX11eRLae3LGfDZ0hSfDR7jZq2ZrKJxyC-LRSSppv72oHKaQMsd-EnoVNL6p7liTh7siN26zzTA_E2rcC_JQ15613Azz4qm8HjPtAyksUdc7QZydszwolk92hBPrAAig
```

Answer (score 0):

Very rough and definitely not the most robust way to do it but

`(?:{(\n|\r|.)*challenge : ')(.*)(?:',)`

or perhaps

`(?:\{(\n|\r|.)*challenge :(\s|\r|\n)*')(.*)(?:',)`

depending on regex implementation/requirements. This second example is a [shown here](http://rubular.com/r/prJOhfCJM5).

Comment: what language are you using? You need to index into the match. Only the string you are wanting is a capturing group. See here... http://rubular.com/r/prJOhfCJM5 ..Notice that the 3rd part of the match is the string you want.